# React native - update item in array with AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to update single item in array, and I don't know how to do it. I tried this approach but it doesn't work.

```
async _updatePoints (value) {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(`@results:${value.scoreId}`, JSON.stringify(value));
  this._updateList();
}
```

As you see, my key in storage is **results**, and i tried to find it my scoreId which is generated random id.

```
scoreId: uuid.v4()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but your syntax is just slightly off. You're trying

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(`@results:${value.scoreId}`, JSON.stringify(value));
```

which maps out to

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(`@[key]:[key for value]`, [value for value]);
```

The correct syntax is actually

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(`@[store]:[key]`, {[key for value]:[value for value]});
```

which maps out to

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(`@appName:results`, JSON.stringify({scoreId:value}));
```